# Get list references from remote private repository LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, repository, ssl-certificate, remote-access, libgit2sharp

**Hello!**

I want connect to private repository. I have login and password, but program stopped in SSL Verification..
Error: `Additional information: this remote has never connected`
How i can fix this error? 
My code:

```
        String urls = "url";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(urls);
        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => false;
        Console.WriteLine(request.AuthenticationLevel);

        var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials
        {
            Username = "user",
            Password = "password"
        };

        var remote = Repository.ListRemoteReferences("url", (url, fromUrl, types) => credentials);

        foreach (var reference in remote)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reference.TargetIdentifier);
        }
```

Can you suggest how to disable the check properly when connected to a repository?

Comment: "How can I fix this error?" Which error? Do you have a concrete error message?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen question updated!

Comment: Whats the connection between your HttpWebRequest and the libgit2sharp-Repository?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All is decided!
The error was in ignorance of the full server repository!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please? What did you change?

Comment: This answer makes no sense and so does the question.